# Anchor link miscalculates expanding layout

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I'm working on a one-page website where the various content is located within different vertically expanding divs. When expanding a div, any already open div will automatically close, and I also want the page to be scrolled so that the particular content positions itself 90px from the top of the browser.

By using a simple anchor-link for each div, this works perfect most of the time. However, as the expanded content increases the height of the website, the anchor will sometimes calculate the 'stopping-point' incorrectly, and the user is scrolled to the wrong place. Especially when expanding a different div straight from an already opened one. I read in an [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416805/why-do-page-anchors-sometimes-miss) question that this is sometimes the case when using anchor links with unforeseen changes in the layout. Does anyone have an idea how to work around this? Is there perhaps a way of 'absolutely' scrolling the new content's position relative to the top of the viewport? Or could one request the anchor to be a bit patient and wait for all the content to load before taking off?

Also, to prevent visitors on mobile and small screens from having to load the full-sized images, the jquery checks the visitor's screen size and loads a corresponding html-file with the correct images into the `#picswitend`. Could this perhaps be a part of the problem?

Here's the code for one of the expanding divs. It's my first attempt at jQuery, so I guess it may be a bit unrefined, but it works.

CSS:

```
  .anchorlink {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top: -90px;
  }
```

Code in `<head>`:

```
  <head>
     <script>
        open = '';
        active = '';
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#closeinfo').hide();
        $('#closethis').hide();
        $('#faq').hide();
        $('#infomore').hide();
        $('#witsend').hide();
        });
     </script>
  </head>
```

Example of one of the expanding divs:

```
  <div class="text">
  <a name="witsendlink" class="anchorlink"></a>
  <a href="#witsendlink" id="witsend-show">
  <script>
     $("#witsend-show").click(function() {      
        $('#' + active).hide();
        $('#' + active + '-show').show();
        $('#infomore').slideUp(200);
        $('#witsend-show').hide();
        $('#witsend').show();
        active = "witsend";
    $('#closethis').show();
    $('#faq').hide();

    if($(this).width() <= 568){
       $("#picswitsend").load("witsendpicsm.html");
    } else {
       $("#picswitsend").load("witsendpics.html");
    }

    $('#witsendtitle').scrollToFixed({
       marginTop: $('#top').outerHeight() - 44,
       limit: function() {
          var limit = $('#lastwitsend').offset().top;
          return limit;
       },
          zIndex: 999,
       });      
        });
  </script>
  <div class="title">
     <p>Wits End Discography</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <p>Siste Sukk tapes & records is a small oslo-based independent label focusing on emo and hardcore, releasing most of their music on tape. When we made the cassette-cover for Wits End's latest release, we wanted to let an unconventional use of material play a major role in the design.
     </p>
  </div>
  </a>

  <div id="witsend">
  <div class="post">

     <div id="witsendtitle">
    <a href="#top" id="witsend-hide">
       <script>
          $('#witsend-hide').click(function () {
                 $('#witsend').hide();
         $('#witsend-show').show();
         $('#closethis').toggle();
         active = '';
      });
       </script>
       <p class="titletext">
          <p class="exit">&#10005;</p> Wits End Discography
       </p>
        </a>
     </div>

 <div class="content open">
    <p>
  <a href="http://www.sistesukk.com">Siste Sukk tapes & records</a> is a small oslo-based independent label focusing on emo and hardcore, releasing most of their music on tape. When we made the cassette-cover for Wits End's latest release, we wanted to let an unconventional use of material play a major role in the design. Basing the cover on a piece of folded newsprint and a and a small plastic bag, it pays respect to old school zine-culture while still keeping a sense of contemporariness and distinction in a scene heavily influenced by D.I.Y solutions.

  Memento mori!<br><br>In collaboration with <a href="http://www.martinmartin.no">Martin Asbj&oslash;rnsen</a>
        </p>
    <p class="small">2012 &middot; Commissioned &middot; <a id="perma" href="http://www.jonasersland.net/index.php?section=witsend#witsend">Permalink <span id="flag"> &#9873;</span></a>
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>        
  <div id="picswitsend">
  </div>                
  </div>
  </div>
```

I'm really thankful if anybody would care to give some thoughts on this, and I'm sorry if I included too little or unrelated information. Please feel free to ask if there's anything, and I'd be thrilled to answer!

Have an absolutely brilliant day.

Edit: Here's the site in action: http://www.jonasersland.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery method scrollTop to "absolutely" scroll to 90px below the top of the browser - and you can animate it to boot so it eases in: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/. What you are trying to do will look like this:

```
$("#linkTopAnchor").click(function() {
    $(this).blur();
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: "90px"}, "fast");
    return false;
});
```

I am using `$(this).blur();` because some mobile devices will automatically scroll to whatever is currently highlighted - so the page will scroll to where you want it and then jump back to the button that initiated event if you don't manually deselect it. I have `return false;` in there to prevent the URL from changing to the hash-tag. In your case, you may want the URL to actually change, so you can simply remove that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! I always thought `scrollTop` only related to the full document itself, and not the browser. Will this script make the clicked element automatically position itself 90px below the top of the browser, regardless of its previous position?

Comment: This script will not change the position of any elements, it will cause the browser itself to scroll - just like clicking the up/down arrows yourself. The previous position of the browser CAN matter if you want it to (for example, you can use scrollTop without any parameters passed in to find out how far the page needs to be scrolled for the top of any element to be visible) but the script I gave you isn't looking for the previous position of the browser. Read through the scrollTop documentation - is is a cool function that you can do a lot with.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant, I just expressed myself a bit awkwardly. Will definitely read up on the scrollTop documentation. Thanks a lot for the help!