# html page loading with different image sizes and anchor links

Tags: html, image, anchor

We have an html page with different image sizes ( about 70 of them). We have a similar problem with image loading and anchor link miss similar to [Why do page anchors sometimes miss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416805/why-do-page-anchors-sometimes-miss)

When given the image width and height it works but is that the only solution or is there something that can be done globally as each image is different and it would be a manual process to update the image sizes.

Appreciate help!
Thanks.

Comment: can u give your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem you are trying correct is with the IMG tag. In most galleries that I have setup for clients I ussually target with css .whateverclass img{ width: 100px or 25%; height: 100px or 25%; }

Another method is to use jQuery and target the img tag and size it that way as well, but CSS is always the best method in my opinion. Let me know if I am completely off on your question.

```
img {
   height: 15%;
   max-height: 50px;
   max-width: 50px;
   width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: yes, i am trying with image tag but if we have 25% or fixed number for all the images, it may stretch or shrink the image as they are all different sizes. so Jquery would be an option to get then image height. I have not used jquery before.

Comment: Not so, if you do % it should as long as you put it for width and height it will scale it proportionally. The first img is 200px the second image is 400 and the third is as well. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/KuEk3/

Comment: I forgot to add max-width: max width will set a cap on your size. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/KuEk3/1/