# HTML anchor link (within-page bookmark) jumps to the wrong spot

Tags: html, anchor

I'm trying to learn HTML (just started); for practice I'm making a page of notes in HTML. I just tried to make an index of five items at the top, using bookmarks. All of them work except one.

The one that's not working is `<p><a href="#empty_element">Empty element</a></p>`. When clicked, it jumps to the Images bookmark. (The Images link also jumps to the Images bookmark, as it should.)

The index is in alphabetical order, and the sections aren't, but several of them are like that and they still work.

`stuff` just means there's a bunch of notes there. If anyone tests this sample as an actual html file, none of the links will work. I think (but am not sure) that's because the page isn't long enough. If paragraphs of lorem ipsum are inserted in place of `stuff`, the problem can be reproduced. But I'm hoping someone can spot what's wrong without that.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/416837/3461693) that images without `width` and `height` attributes can cause trouble, so I added those to the image that's in the Images section and included it below, but it didn't help. Another comment says it can be a page-loading issue, but the comment's beyond me. I don't have any scripts as mentioned in the comment, just HTML and some CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Index</h2>
<p><a href="#displaying_code">Displaying code</a></p>
<p><a href="#empty_element">Empty element</a></p>
<p><a href="#headings">Headings</a></p>
<p><a href="#images">Images</a></p>
<p><a href="#links">Links</a></p>

stuff
<h2 id="headings">Headings</h2>
stuff
<h2 id="displaying_code">Displaying code:</h2>
stuff
<h2 id="links">Links:</h2>
stuff
<h2 id="images">Images:</h2>
stuff
<img src="shrug.png" width="60" height="60">
<h2 id="empty_element">Empty element:</h2>
stuff

</body>
</html>
```

Here's a simpler example, to try to see if page length is the problem, per discussion in comments.

There's a link at the top, a very long section of lorem ipsum, and a heading (the target) at the bottom.

It still doesn't work as expected (Vivaldi, Chrome, Edge, Firefox).

Expected: clicking the link results in the heading being displayed at the top of the screen.

Actual: the screen shifts upwards just enough to make the heading visible at the *bottom* of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="#one">Section One</a>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac nisl euismod, ullamcorper neque laoreet, consequat enim. Aenean in aliquam nisi. Sed vel magna non urna mattis feugiat sit amet sit amet massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In egestas, dolor a eleifend sollicitudin, tortor dolor ullamcorper lacus, ut feugiat diam est posuere sapien. Nulla blandit vestibulum bibendum. Phasellus suscipit erat lectus, eu molestie sem congue a. Aenean et pulvinar nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin nec rhoncus tortor, et commodo purus.</p>

<h1 id="one">Section One</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should add your full code, I tried your example and it worked fine.

Comment: @AlexAngelico Oh how weird. I just (once again) copy/pasted directly from the code box up above into Notepad, and then opened it in my browser, and same as before, none of the links go to the right places. Sigh. My full code is full of jibber-jabber I don't particularly want on the internet... not sure what I want to do now. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, it doesn't seem to be browser-related. Have tried it in Vivaldi, Edge, Chrome, and Firefox and they all behave in the same wrong way.

Comment: I think your code is working, the problem is as you said, the page isn't long enough so it looks like you been redirected to images, but you are at empty element.The only other issue I can think of is you have another element with the same `id="empty_element"`

Comment: Thanks for trying again, Alex. No, there's only one `id="empty_element"` (confirmed with ctrl-f). I added an even simpler example to my question, does that shed any light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I think these clues have solved it. It does have to do with length, as Alex said in comments, specifically the length of the bottom section.

From [this page by the Nielsen Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/in-page-links/):

> Pay attention to the last section of content on the page. If the last piece of content is short and there are few links or elements beneath it on the page, it is possible it will appear in the middle rather than at the top of the page. When possible, try to ensure that the content for that last section is long enough.

And this from [AGConsult](https://www.agconsult.com/en/usability-blog/anchor-links-dos-and-donts/):

> Make sure the anchor links jump to the right sub-heading in every commonly used screen resolution. This may mean you have to add white space at the bottom of the page.

On my original page, the last section ("Empty element") was indeed very short, only 2 sentences. I added a section of `<br>` tags between it and `</body>`, and now all the anchor links work perfectly. Through trial and error, it took about 24 `<br>` tags for that particular page with my laptop's screen resolution.

This also explains why the second code sample in my question worked so badly - there's nothing at all below the "Section One" heading.